# Azure Pipeline YML Conditional Environment Variable

Tags: azure-devops

In the example YML task how do I assign a conditional environment value to the env. variable `SOME_VARIABLE`.

```yaml
- task: Powershell@2
  displayName: 'Some Random Name'
  env:
    SOME_VARIABLE: Development
```

For example, I want to do something like the following, but I'm not sure if that is correct.

```yaml
- task: Powershell@2
  displayName: 'Some Random Name'
  env:
    ${{ if eq(lower(parameters.whatever), 'foo') }}:
      SOME_VARIABLE: Yay
    ${{ if eq(lower(parameters.whatever), 'bar') }}:
      SOME_VARIABLE: Boo
```

Comment: Did you *try* your proposed solution? You asked this question 32 minutes ago and you could have answered it yourself in a few seconds.

Comment: @DanielMann no, I wanted to check my hypothesis on here before trying.

Comment: Not sure you can use it with env but you can conditionally all sort of stuff: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion

Comment: Your example code should work